# softKeyboard is opening and closing when edit text is focused inside cardview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-softkeyboard, android-cardview

I am using MergeRecycleAdapter with recyclerview to add multiple views and adapters.When I put them inside cardview and Edittext view is focused keyboard is opening and immediately closing.Without cardview it works fine like Resizing screen. For that I have written one sample activity.I couldn't figure out where I am missing.

Manifest

```
 <activity
        android:name=".activity.KeyboardActivity"
        android:configChanges="navigation|orientation|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/ibhubs"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Layout xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:descendantFocusability="afterDescendants"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:isScrollContainer="false" />

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Activity code

```
public class KeyboardActivity extends BaseActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.keyboard_merge_recycler_adapter);
        initializeViews();
    }
    private void initializeViews() {
        RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
        MergeRecycleAdapter mergeRecycleAdapter = new MergeRecycleAdapter();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            EditText editText = new EditText(this);
            editText.setText(String.valueOf(i));
            mergeRecycleAdapter.addView(editText);
        }
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(mergeRecycleAdapter);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is that `MergeRecycleAdapter` ? Where did you get it?

Comment: you can not add view to adapter  mergeRecycleAdapter.addView(editText); is not correct.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/athornz/008edacd1d3b2f1e1836 you can find here @Divers

Comment: @DineshChitta and why and for what do you use that adaptor? Did you read description - `This adapter essentially merges a collection of adapters/views into one adapter.` ?

Comment: @Divers yes. I use it for adding multiple views and adapters into one adapter.Since It is difficult to maintain multiple recyclerviews in one layout because of scroll issues etc . .